# How can i make a function wait without freezing the whole thread

Tags: c++, winapi

```
bool find1(const char* name)
{
    
    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    auto snapshot = LI_FN(CreateToolhelp32Snapshot).safe()(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

    if (LI_FN(Process32First).safe()(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
    {
        while (LI_FN(Process32Next).safe()(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
        {
            if (strstr(entry.szExeFile, name))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    LI_FN(CloseHandle).safe()(snapshot);
    return false;
}
```

I have this code included in a void where it will execute itself in every tick. This lags the application a lot , so i need to run it every 5 seconds. How do i add delay or sleep it without sleeping the whole thread (in my case the app fully freezing)

Edit (this looks if a program is opened)
This script will be used to find and close any debug programs that open while the app is running so i need it running continually.

Comment: You cannot sleep part of a thread, but you could add another thread.

Comment: Presumably you have a message loop or something somewhere. Keep track of the last time you ran the check and the current time. When 5 seconds or whatever period of time you like has elapsed since the last time call the function again and reset the last time variable.

Comment: If you don't want this code blocking the UI thread, move it to a separate worker thread. Also, this code is skipping the 1st process reported, use a `do..while` loop instead of a `loop`. Also, this code is not closing the `snapshot` if a matching name is found.

Comment: *"included in a void"* -- sounds like you've made this code no longer exist (part of an empty space, a.k.a. [a void](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/void#Noun)). Do you mean that this code is called from a *function* (where the function's return type happens to be `void`, but that detail has no bearing on this question)?

Comment: you can create another thread that SetTimer(5 sec) then enters main-loop
when the new thread receives wm_timer it call above code

Comment: Probably an useless idea that will only slow down the whole computer with marginal utility. Ordinary people won't debug your program (without source code) and those that might want to do it will probably find a way to be unclosable, restart itself or neutralize your code (for ex. by remote killing the thread that call `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` in the 5 seconds windows).

Comment: A classic case of the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). If you need to know when a particular process is created, register a callback. WMI allows you to do that. Or you could use ETW to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

Thread is a flow of CPU commands, it is either run, or sleep (paused/put away) (sleep), or stopped (or came to the end).

You could create a special thread where would be a loop and inside the loop the task you are interested in and sleep for the time you need.